# Tags: "Handheld", "HT", or both?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

HT is definitely the more common jardon, but "handheld" is less jargon-y for those new to radio. Should we prefer one over the other (and/or tag synonym one to the other), or should we allow using both side by side if desired?

Answer (score 8):

Yes the tags can be synonyms.

I suggest we use Handheld as the master.

Comment: That still leaves the question of what that one tag should be. `ht`? `handheld`? Tags typically don't contain ampersands.

Comment: You can use either and they system will make them identical.

Comment: ...yes, but you have to tell the system to do that, and it requires a 'master' tag which all other synonyms will be turned into. So there's still the question of which should be the master.

Comment: Thanks for helping me clarify -- I updated the answer.

Comment: **handheld**  If possible, add **handy** (and **handie**) as a synonym.  (Will the system translate synonyms to the master if asked?)

Comment: Synonyms are automatically translated into the master tag, yes. (I can't actually suggest the synonym yet because it requires 1250 rep. A moderator could go ahead and add it, though.)

Answer (score 3):

I have merged these tags as suggested. [portable](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portable) is still a separate tag to refer to any handheld (or portable) equipment rather than a radio. [handheld](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handheld) is now a synonym of [ht](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ht). I kept [ht](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ht) as the master for the following reasons:

- More popular in existing use - 6 uses of [ht](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ht) to 3 uses of [handheld](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handheld) (plus 2 with both)
- More descriptive name - even though [ht](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ht) is an abbreviation, it more accurately reflects what the tag is used for. "HT" is nearly universally understood, while "handheld" could refer to a cell phone or GPS receiver.

If we see any other alternative spellings used ([tag:handy, [handie](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handie), [handheld-transceiver](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handheld-transceiver)) then we'll make more synonyms. (Unless I'm missing something, I can't mod-create a synonym unless the proposed synonym is actually in use.)

Comment: It won't let me edit, but you are missing a closing bracket on the first tag: [tag:handy]